# How to prove the following inequality? (or a counter example)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, functions

We know that we have $[\int |f(x)|^{p} \mu(dx)]^{1/p}\leq [\int |f(x)|^{q} \mu(dx)]^{1/q}$ when $p\leq q$, where $\mu$ is a probability measure and $f$ is a smooth function. Do we in general have the following inequality:

$[\int \left(|f(x)|^{p} + \sum_{i=1}^n |f^{(i)}(x)|^{p} \right)\mu(dx)]^{1/p}\leq [\int \left(|f(x)|^{q} + \sum_{i=1}^n |f^{(i)}(x)|^{q}\right) \mu(dx)]^{1/q}$

How to prove it, or construct a counter example to disprove the above inequality?

Comment: it is true, if $\mu$ is a probability measure. otherwise you forgot some constants.

Comment: How to prove it if $\mu$ is a probability measure? I suspect to use Mathematical Induction. For me to check it, I try to check for several simple case first. If $n=0$, it is trivial to use Holder inequality. How about if $n=1$? It becomes addition and Holder inequality cannot be applied. Any tricks here so that I can use to prove for $n=1$ case?

Comment: I meant your initial inequality is true, if $\mu$ is a probability measure. you also need to weight your second inequality to make it right. see [Hölder mean](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean). Both follow from the Hölder inequality. Are you sure that you need these inequalities in exact that form? wouldn't up to some constants be sufficient?

Comment: then, it is wrong as it state. notice that $\|(1,1)\|_1 = 2 > \sqrt{2} = \|(1,1)\|_2$.

Comment: Indeed, I need to prove 

$[\int \left(|f(x)|^{p} + \sum_{i=1}^n |f^{(i)}(x)|^{p} \right)\mu(dx)]^{1/p}\leq [\int \left(|f(x)|^{q} + \sum_{i=1}^k |f^{(i)}(x)|^{q}\right) \mu(dx)]^{1/q}$

where $p\leq q$ and $n\leq k$. This is so called semi norm property and I do not understand how to apply Holder inequality to prove it. Also, I think of an example. $\mu$ is normal measure, $f=x$, $p=2$, $q=3$. The inequality does not hold.

Comment: I am very curious. On one hand, there is a book who states that it is correct, but at the same time, an example is constructed to disprove the statement. Which side is correct?

Comment: Since the example is so simple, it must be correct ;)

Comment: please post an excerpt of the that book. and I am not sure what that has to do with semi norms...

Answer (score 0):

I read this from the book called "The Malliavin Calculus and related Topics", p.27. In fact, it is an expectation question.

$(E[|F|^{p}]+\sum_{i}E[||D^{i}F||_{H^{i}}^{p}])^{1/p} \leq (E[|F|^{q}]+\sum_{i}E[||D^{i}F||_{H^{i}}^{q}])^{1/q}$

After simplification, it suffices to prove

$[\int \left(|f(x)|^{p} + \sum_{i=1}^n |f^{(i)}(x)|^{p} \right)\mu(dx)]^{1/p}\leq [\int \left(|f(x)|^{q} + \sum_{i=1}^n |f^{(i)}(x)|^{q}\right) \mu(dx)]^{1/q}$

If someone suggests that they can prove it using Holder inequality, then I should not get such weird result. If it can be proved, I would like to know the derivation of the proof and which part is wrong for the counter example.